# I can't choose a background image

Tags: html, css

I have the following code. Why is my background white?  I have the image in the correct folder.

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height:100%;
  font-size:40pt;
  background-image:url ("Foto1.html");
}
```

Ok thanks now the file is Foto1.jpg and the code is `background-image: url("Foto1.jpg");`
... but it still doesn't work...

Comment: Because the image would not have a `html` filetype name. It should probably be `.jpg` or `.png` or similar

Comment: Thanks... I replaced html with jpg and the file in the folder, but it still doesn't work...

Comment: Then perhaps you don't have the right path.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot use a .html file as a background image in css, you should rather use a .jpg, .png or any other css supported background image file.

Invalid:

```
background-image:url ("Foto1.html");
```

Valid:

```
background-image:url ("Foto1.jpg");
```

Comment: Thanks... I replaced html with jpg and the file in the folder, but it still doesn't work...

Comment: Are you sure that you have a file with name "Foto1.jpg"?

Answer (score 0):

This is because html is not a image extension, you need to take the picture out first in a classic format like png, jpg etc...

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space between "url" and "("

background-image:url("Foto1.jpg");